Elasticsearch: I cannot create grouping aggregation results based on two different objects
I'm trying to create an aggregation by rssProvider and rssCategory.
Here is what I have so far
This is the output of the current aggregation. Note: Raw migrations are processed with custom code logic for transforming it into this format:
"aggs": {
        "rssProviders": [
            {
                "title": "Gesundheit",
                "id": 4,
                "docCount": 387
            },
            {
                "title": "Neueste Nachrichten",
                "id": 3,
                "docCount": 303
            },
            {
                "title": "tagesschau.de - die erste Adresse für Nachrichten und Information",
                "id": 1,
                "docCount": 297
            },
            {
                "title": "Reisen & Leben",
                "id": 8,
                "docCount": 294
            },
            {
                "title": "Politik",
                "id": 5,
                "docCount": 254
            },
            {
                "title": "Film",
                "id": 2,
                "docCount": 250
            },
            {
                "title": "Karriere - SZ.de",
                "id": 7,
                "docCount": 193
            },
            {
                "title": "Verkehrsmeldungen des Bayerischen Rundfunks",
                "id": 16,
                "docCount": 108
            },
            {
                "title": "Regionalnachrichten aus Baden-Württemberg",
                "id": 13,
                "docCount": 78
            },
            {
                "title": "Stadtverwaltung Friedrichshafen",
                "id": 10,
                "docCount": 74
            }
        ],
        "rssCategories": [
            {
                "title": "Aktuelles Überregional",
                "id": 2,
                "docCount": 1364
            },
            {
                "title": "Gesellschaft Überregional",
                "id": 4,
                "docCount": 707
            },
            {
                "title": "Regionales Baden-Württemberg",
                "id": 6,
                "docCount": 192
            },
            {
                "title": "Regionales Bodensee",
                "id": 5,
                "docCount": 113
            },
            {
                "title": "Wirtschaft Überregional",
                "id": 3,
                "docCount": 89
            }
        ]
    }

This is the elastic snippet in node.js that generates the aggregation
aggs: payload.aggs ? {
      rssProviders: {
        multi_terms: {
          terms: [{
            field: 'provider.title.keyword',
          }, {
            field: 'provider.id',
          }],
        },
      },
      rssCategories: {
        nested: {
          path: 'rssCategory',
        },
        aggs: {
          rss_category_titles: {
            multi_terms: {
              terms: [{
                field: 'rssCategory.title',
              }, {
                field: 'rssCategory.id',
              }],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    } : undefined,

This is the mapping of the said values that I'm using for aggregation
"provider": {
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "photoURL": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "url": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "rssCategory": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },

I am trying to achieve the following format:
"category1": {
        "provider1": {
            ...
        },
        "provider3": {
            ...
        }
    },
    "category2": {
        provider4: {
            ...
        },
        provider5: {
            ...
        }
    }

NOTE: I would also prefer to use multi-terms if possible so I can extract both id and title of both  providers and its categories
This is what I have so far (written in devtools since it's not working properly yet)
"aggs": {
    "rssCategories": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "rssCategory"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "rssCategories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "rssCategory.title",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "providerTerms": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "provider.title.keyword",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

For that I got the following:
"aggregations": {
    "rssCategories": {
      "doc_count": 11701,
      "rssCategories": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Aktuelles Überregional",
            "doc_count": 7441,
            "providerTerms": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Gesellschaft Überregional",
            "doc_count": 3564,
            "providerTerms": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Regionales Baden-Württemberg",
            "doc_count": 336,
            "providerTerms": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Regionales Bodensee",
            "doc_count": 209,
            "providerTerms": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Wirtschaft Überregional",
            "doc_count": 151,
            "providerTerms": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }

I'm missing the providers in the corresponding buckets as well as the ids of individual categories
